# iOS Analyze .crash data without dSYM

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin, app-store

As you can tell from the title, I am in a sticky situation where my App is crashing after performing a specific test. The test is as follows:

1. install App on iPhone 7
2. transfer iCloud profile to iPhone X
3. launch App (app will show splash screen and fail)

I was able to recuperate the .crash data from the iPhoneX however the data isnt very useful as the calls being made are all in hex. I am aware you can try to analyze the data through **atos** as well as other tools from this [help link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) however it seems you always need the **dSYM** for most of the cases. I have the original .app and .ipa that was used to publish the app however there are no **.dSYM** files on the build machine. (I believe by default Apple has it set to build DWARF without dSYM)

Is there any way I can put the data from my **.crash** file to good use? The file is completely unsymbolicated.

(As a side note, a way to get out of the App crashing at launch after doing the iCloud transfer is to uninstall and reinstall the app from the App store. Not fun for an end user)

Snippet of the crash:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found
Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183f202e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184039748 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 360
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183e8efbc abort + 140
3   MyApp                           0x0000000105ad4de8 0x104be8000 + 15650280
```

Comment: better you can put crash logs here

Comment: I would prefer not to upload my all of the crash data as it can contain sensitive information. I did update a portion of the question if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can put the data from my .crash file to good use without DSYM ?

No, it is impossible.

DSYM file stores all the debug symbols, with it we can find the corresponding function name  via the memory address(in crash file) which leads to crash.